# CSS locator for corresponding xpath for selenium

Tags: selenium, css-selectors, selenium-rc

The some part of the html of the webpage which I'm testing looks like this

```
<div id="twoWideCallouts">

<div class="callout">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://facebook.com">Facebook</a>
</div>

<div class="callout last">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://youtube.com">Youtube</a>
</div>
```

I've to check using selenium that when I click on text, the URL opened is the same that is given in href and not error page.

Using Xpath I've written the following command

```
//i is iterator
selenium.getAttribute("//div[contains(@class, 'callout')]["+i+"]/a/@href")
```

However, this is very slow and for some of the links doesn't work. By reading many answers and comments on this site I've come to know that CSS loactors are faster and cleaner to maintain so I wrote it again as

```
css = div:contains(callout)
```

Firstly, I'm not able to reach to the anchor tag.

Secondly, This page can have any number of div where id = callout. Using xpathcount i can get the count of this, and I'll be iterating on that count and performing the href check. How can something similar be done using CSS locator?

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I can click on the link using the locator `css=div.callout a`, but when I try to read the href value using `String str = "css=div.callout a[href]";
            selenium.getAttribute(str);`. I get the Error - element not found. Console description is given below.

```
19:12:33.968 INFO - Command request: getAttribute[css=div.callout a[href], ] on session 
19:12:33.993 INFO - Got result: ERROR: Element css=div.callout a[href not found on session
```

I tried to get the href attribute using xpath like this

```
"xpath=(//div[contains(@class, 'callout')])["+1+"]/a/@href" and it worked fine.
```

Please tell me what should be the corresponding CSS locator for this.

Comment: Complaining about XPath is not the same as asking about XPath... Retagging.

Comment: I'm not complaining, I just explained my observation, probably I'll be able to post questions in better way with more experience.I just wanted to know a way to address the problem in a more effecient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the sttribute I used `css=div.callout a@href` and it worked. The problem was with use of square brackets around attribute name.

Comment: what is the exact semantics of the @ sign here? Is it CSS3? I can't find it on http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: @ is for accessing an attribute. It is not CSS3

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, anchor your identifier on the hyperlink:

```
css=a[href=http://youtube.com]
```

For achieving a count of elements in the DOM, based on CSS selectors, here's an [excellent article](http://www.eviltester.com/index.php/2010/03/13/a-simple-getcsscount-helper-method-for-use-with-selenium-rc/).

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to check all the hrefs that exist under class = callout. Is there a way to  relatively look for Child's attribute value if only parent is given using CSS locators? Thanks again for the link.

Answer (score 0):

It should be -

css = div:contains(callout)

Did you notice ":" instead of "." you used?

For CSSCount this might help -

http://www.eviltester.com/index.php/2010/03/13/a-simple-getcsscount-helper-method-for-use-with-selenium-rc/

#

On a different note, did you see proposal of new selenium site on area 51 - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4693/selenium.

#

Comment: Thanks, I changed that in edit, please see the updated info. I've gone thru this link, I'll be able to count elements using this. The place where I'm stuck now is, to get the attribute value, as I've to compare this with that inside CMS.

Comment: Not sure if element locator is the answer here, did you consider using html parser like jsoup

Comment: No, I didn't, but I'll check that out. Thanks.